# Python Pandas, replace filepath in each row of a column with directory path?

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried for a few hours now to find someone who has asked a similar query but none seem to satisfy exactly what is need!

I have a data frame with a column named `['File_Path']`. This column contains file paths such as

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3/IMG_444.jpg 
/folder1/folder2/folder3/IMG_445.jpg
/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
```

I want just the directory path, so `'IMG_444.JPG'` and `'IMG_445.jpg`' would be omitted from their respective strings.

I have tried:

```
df['File_Path'] = df['File_Path'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(x, os.path.dirname(x)))
```

But this prints whitespace. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: as an aside, why not `lambda x: os.path.dirname(x)`, dropping `replace`?

Comment: may be just `df['File_Path'] = df['File_Path'].apply(os.path.dirname)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `df.apply` with `os.path.dirname`

**Ex:**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Path": ['/folder1/folder2/folder3/IMG_444.jpg ', '/folder1/folder2/folder3/IMG_445.jpg', '/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4']})
df["Path"] = df["Path"].apply(os.path.dirname)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                       Path
0  /folder1/folder2/folder3
1  /folder1/folder2/folder3
2  /folder1/folder2/folder3
```

Comment: can `transform`